# Found and switched to an iframe, but cannot find IWebElement in it

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium

html code:

```
<iframe title="javascript:''" src="PageName.aspx" _events="[object Object]">
    <htlml>
        <head>
            <body>
                 <form name="FormName">
                      <div>
                          <span>
                               <input name="ButtonName>
```

My question: how can I find the element with name "ButtonName"?
My current code in C#

```
//To find the iframe
IWebElement Object = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("XPath to the iframe");   //works
//To switch to and set focus to the iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Object);  //works

//To find element with name "ButtonName"
IWebElement Button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));  //error: cannot find the element
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess this question is about Selenium, and it should be added to tags and question.

Comment: Is 'Oject' and 'Object' misspelling only in question?

Comment: Hi user1177636, Thanks for your comment. It could be the case that frame switching failed. How can I verify that? How can I make the switching successful?

Answer (score 2):

Please use: **driver**.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));

Try this code:

**Default.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="Default2.aspx"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Default2.aspx:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <span>
          <input type="button" name="ButtonName" class="test" onclick="alert(1);" />
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I ran the Default.aspx through visual studio. Then I used the url to my Default.aspx in my console application. I wrote the following code inside the main function of my console application:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver
{
    Url = "http://localhost:13764/WebSite1/Default.aspx"
};

IWebElement objecElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html//body//iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(objecElement);
driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName")).Click();
```

When I run my console application, I see an alert in my Firefox window, which was launched by the above code.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The code still cannot find the button inside the iframe. What should I do to make things work?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498560/webdriverwait-is-not-working/19504760#19504760) question yesterday. You put the element in an IWebElement variable and didn't use it.

Either do as user197586 pointed out:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));
```

Or do something with the element variable:

```
IWebElement Button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));
Button.DoSomething();
```

If you're just checking that an element appears, you don't need to assign it to an IWebElement variable. If you're going to use the element later, make sure you actually use it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I corrected my question and I am not sure why my edit is not reflected on the website. This is my code, which still does not work
IWebElement Object = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("XPath to the iframe");   
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Object);  //works
IWebElement Button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));

Comment: Yeh, so on that second part you're putting: 
IWebElement Button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));

As I explained above, if you assign a FindElement to an IWebElement and don't use the IWebElement, it won't find your element. You need to do something with the IWebElement or just use:
driver.FindElement(By.Name("ButtonName"));

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, I use IWebElement variable if I can find it to verify if it is enabled (Button.Enabled). Also, I tried your answer with other button in the iframe, and the element still cannot be found. This is the screenshot of actual run: http://screencast.com/t/X3K6a6ELgbk  Can you take a look to see if I miss anything (there is only 1 iframe in html and the button is on a form in the iframe). Thanks.

Comment: I can't watch the screencast at the moment, but I just wondered something. Have you tried CSS instead of Name? "input[name='ButtonName']"

Comment: Yes, I have tried this code: IWebElement Button = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ibtn")); Button.Click(); Still the button cannot be found.

Comment: I think the others above are probably correct then. You're likely not in the proper frame. Hope you can figure it out!