# WebDriverWait is not working

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Windows 8, IE 10 (java - WebDriver 2.37.0) and I am trying to wait until the element is loaded  on the page. I used following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://abc.com");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

But it's throwing a timeout exception. If I remove this code, it's able to identify the element on the webdriver.

I tried the same code in other browsers as FireFox, Chrome but its still throwing error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is an element with the ID "myDynamicElement" present on the page?

Comment: Yes it is present on the page. If I remove the above wait code, it is identifying that element.

Comment: when does it throw this exception? after 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes.. In By.ID - Can we identify it using xPath also or it has to be ID only?

Comment: You can try xpath, sure. It would probably be something like `By.xpath("//[@id='myDynamicElement']")`. However that should be identical to the ID search; also if you find the element outside of the wait it shouldn't make any difference at all. Interestingly, this example seems to be nearly identical to the example on http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits so the syntax should be correct; it's probably something about the page.

Comment: Very interesting. Obviously, the code is good. You either found a bug, or something on the page is not behaving the way you think. Anyway, we need a reproducible test case to confirm any of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning that wait to the variable myDynamicElement. If you don't give the WebElement variable something to do, Selenium will throw that timeout exception. If you just want to wait for the element to be present then there is no need to assign it to a WebElement variable.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://abc.com");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

If you need to assign that variable for later use then do something with the element.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement =
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
myDynamicElement.isDisplayed();
```

Comment: What. Could you please elaborate on what you just wrote? If I understood it right, you're wrong. If I misunderstood it, I think it's safe to say that the answer might use some reasoning. Why would assigning a returned element to a variable change anything?

Comment: I just tested it myself to see what he was talking about. When you assign the WebDriverWait to a variable, you have to use the variable or it will throw the timeout exception. Might be a defect but I'm able to reproduce what he's talking about and the fix is to not assign it to a variable or use the variable.

Comment: I changed my code to-                                           WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(myD, 10);

waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@name='footer_site_map']")));
   This code is working in both Chrome and FireFox browsers but its not working on IE10. Any idea why this is happening? Basically I am trying to wait only until the element is loaded on the page. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: No problem! That's much better usage of WebDriverWait.
IE10 might have problems with the xpath. If you can, use CSS here:

By.cssSelector("a[name='footer_site_map']")

Comment: Thanks NaviSaysListen . will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void waitForElementToAppear(Driver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
  }
```